# CSP style-src failing to recognize SHA?

Tags: css, security

Here is the direct error message I am getting from the Chrome dev tools:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src
>   'sha256-1nVQdHiAzq+yQt4PZ8OE7a29XlxBFIzESqqj+rz4Jdc=' 'self'". Either
>   the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-1nVQdHiAzq+yQt4PZ8OE7a29XlxBFIzESqqj+rz4Jdc='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Now it seems to me that it is saying that the policy with the hash doesn't contain the needed hash. Am I missing something in my syntax? I get the CSP error from Firefox as well (though with fewer details).

Here's the header directly:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; style-src 'sha256-1nVQdHiAzq+yQt4PZ8OE7a29XlxBFIzESqqj+rz4Jdc=' 'self';
```

Comment: What inline CSS style are you trying to apply?

Comment: We've been trying to track it down, but I believe it is coming out of a combination of Angular.js and our minification process. Until we have cycles to root it out, we would like to just permit it as a white listed exception.

Comment: Are you running both CSP and CSP-report-only? Have seen problems like this when the two policies are used together: https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/csp/#support

Comment: No, just CSP. I've confirmed that I'm not using the report-only header.

Comment: I'm also seeing this with inline styles injected by jQuery and FontAwesome 5. I'm only sending the CSP header, not the report-only header, and am seeing the issue with ngCsp enabled or disabled in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Possibly because hashes only apply to `<style>` elements, not `style=` attributes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52795613/3257984