# Sha hash not respected in CSP style-src

Tags: content-security-policy, validationsummary

I have an ASP.NET web application that makes use of `asp-validation-summary`. Because of this an inline `style` is added to an HTML element in my page.

This gives me the following error in console (Chrome v78.0.3904.108) when I run my application:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

So I added the hash to my CSP, which now looks like this:

```
style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE=';
```

When I load my page I still get a similar error:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

This is the entire CSP header:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
```

As you can see I've added the hash, as sugested in the error. It also seems to be a [valid header](https://cspvalidator.org/#headerValue%5B%5D=default-src+'self'%3B+object-src+'none'%3B+frame-ancestors+'none'%3B+sandbox+allow-forms+allow-same-origin+allow-scripts%3B+base-uri+'self'%3B+upgrade-insecure-requests%3B+style-src+'self'+https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.googleapis.com+'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE%3D'%3B+font-src+'self'+https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.gstatic.com%3B&strategy=intersection).

But why isn't this working?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I also verified the suggested hash is correct, and validated my CSP.

Comment: Same issue, would've been nice if this was answered by now. :)

Comment: Possible explanation of this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52795613/1023562

Answer (score 2):

You must add `unsafe-hashes`.
`unsafe-hashes` allows to enable specific inline event handlers. If you only need to allow inline event handlers and not inline  elements or javascript: URLs, this is a safer method compared to using the unsafe-inline expression.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src

Comment: Is there a "safe" way to do this?

It's maddening that adding hashes doesn't work until you add the unsafe-hashes keyword, and it's very confusing that something that targets "inline event handlers" is actually necessary for inline styles.