# This policy contains 'unsafe-inline' which is dangerous in the script-src directive

Tags: vue.js, content-security-policy

Our Vue js website contains dynamic url of css and src by different environment. Each environment have different domains. So the Content-Security-Policy contains
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
and
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'

But it gives a warning "This policy contains 'unsafe-inline' which is dangerous in the script-src directive. This policy contains 'unsafe-inline' which is dangerous in the style-src directive."

How can we handle dynamic urls for sript-src and style-src?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, too.
Hope that my solution will help.

First, remove `'unsafe-inline'` and run your applications
You may get some errors from console on the web.
For example:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
> https://fonts.googleapis.com
> **'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='**". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Second, copy the text `'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='` and put in Content-Security-Policy after **script-src** or **style-src**
For example:

> default-src 'none'; font-src 'self' data:; img-src 'self'; script-src
> 'self' **'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='**; style-src 'self'
> **'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE='**; object-src
> 'self'; connect-src 'self'

And this may solve your problem.

By the way, you may encounter the problem like this :
[Sha hash not respected in CSP style-src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057957/sha-hash-not-respected-in-csp-style-src)

You can add 'unsafe-hashes' after **script-src** or **style-src** to solve it.