# Violating CSP even though I added the right SHA

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy, sha

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' **'sha256-o/kbe6RnURgWNmQt/lS02Rrn0WWOYgK9UupCx39FTBI='** 'sha256-v9Mw9x7yMApHnSPDExzKqU3NtzpjJzqCFAjKU2czIRo=' 'sha256-udQJaD2iLjLPwDBs5CIgWma5W3O8BHOI9Sy+17DR6tk=' 'nonce-33bbb484-d955-42ee-ac5a-5864f5cb4f59'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash (**'sha256-o/kbe6RnURgWNmQt/lS02Rrn0WWOYgK9UupCx39FTBI='**), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

As you can see, I have added the exact SHA the browser is suggesting me to add for the `style-src` directive. Is this a browser bug...what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: [Why doesn't Chrome respect my Content Security Policy hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724956/why-doesnt-chrome-respect-my-content-security-policy-hashes/52795613#52795613)